# Заменить "+" в url на пробел %20

Tags: javascript, php, html

Использую такую форму:

```
 <form name="form" class="search-form-home" action="/home-designs" method="get">
    <div class="input_block">
        <i></i>
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="fwp_locations_home_design" class="search_input_homepage" placeholder="Suburb, region" value="" >
        <input type="hidden" name="fwp_storey" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="fwp_bathroom" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="fwp_bedroom" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="fwp_price_slider" value="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

В input ввожу следующее: Melbourne Area

На выходе получаю следующий url: `https://mysite.com/home-designs/?fwp_locations_home_design=Melbourne+Area`

Как можно в `Melbourne+Area` заменить плюс на %20(пробел)?

Comment: Зачем? Плюс — вполне законный символ, обозначающий как раз пробел наравне с %20.

Answer (score 1):

[`.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
let str = 'https://mysite.com/home-designs/?fwp_locations_home_design=Melbourne+Area+asd++++++des';
str = str.replace(/\+/g, '%20');
console.info(str);
```